# Prevent Husky from digging up prior dog's burial site

Tags: dogs, digging

*Backstory*

My ex-girlfriend asked me to buy her a Husky puppy back in January. The ex-girlfriend is back to living with her ex-husband and today apparently the dog started digging in the area of their yard where the ex-husband's beloved pet is poorly buried.

My dilemma is that I love the dog, but am a single person living in a 1 bedroom apartment, working 10+ hours per day away from home, thus I can't adopt the Husky. So I'm trying to keep the ex-girlfriend from taking the dog to the pound.

***Attempted Solutions***

I have suggested that rather than getting rid of the pet, she consider:

- cremating the prior dog
- having the prior dog reburied in a proper pet cemetary
- putting bricks or something handy over the burial site
- just getting over it because the dog is very unlikely to dig *that* deep

Apparently none of these were acceptable solutions.

***Needed Solution***

If there are any ideas I'm not thinking of, then I'm all ears.

Otherwise, would anyone know of some sort of classy-looking marble type stone they might make for this purpose to effectively seal the burial area in the yard from the Husky's digging? I've been searching on the Internet but with no success....

Comment: That girl is not very committed to the dog if none of those options are acceptable.

Comment: I hear you. I said the same thing, but part of it is probably that her kids saw it and it upset them and part of it is also probably that it just happened. Hopefully this will all blow over in a few days...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most cost and actually effective solution  to keep the dog from digging in that area, I would remove the top 2 - 3 inches of sod over the burial site. Lay down a piece of [chain link fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-link_fencing) replace the sod.  The grass will easily re-root through the fence. The dog will not be able to dig through it.  The buried dog will decompose faster then the chain link fence.

[image: Fence Image]

The most effective way to protect the Husky pup is to re-home it. Based on your description she does not want the dog.  Even if you have the perfect solution she is going to have another reason to take the dog to the pound a little later.  If the dog is pure breed Husky contact [Husky House](http://www.huskyhouse.org/) or a local Husky Rescue in your area.

Lastly contact your local shelter/pound they often have waiting lists for people looking for pure breed or nearly pure breed dogs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer/solution! It's a good idea. I actually managed to smooth things over in a slightly different way (2" thick granite slab grave ledger from eBay sold as some sort of tool utility + paw shaped headstone + bitter apple spray + Husky toys to get the kids back on the dog's side), but +1 for this great idea and I will mark it as the solution